# GITHub API Issue with file upload

Tags: git, github, github-api

I am trying to upload file to GitHub via GITHub API (http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/). Somehow I am not able to upload file. When I tried to upload existing file it gave me message "{\"message\":\"refs/heads/master expected to be at ee1cd720841a4b5b06a8339c333c56b1748e66f9\",\"documentation_url\":\"http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/\"}". When I went to github and tried to delete file using website it gave me below error. I can do workaround with reset head to previous version and move on. But I am trying to understand what caused this behavior and how can I prevent same in future. Neither Google nor Github Help was able to answer me so looking for something from community. Thanks for looking into it. 
[image]

Comment: Are you by chance using the Repositories API to write to the repository in quick succession? For example, are you creating multiple files by making new API calls before the previous calls have completed?

Comment: Thanks for response Ivan !! Your assumption is right. I am trying to create multiple files in succession as part of deployment process. On the side note though I am doing synchronous uploads so once I receive response back from GiHub API ok 200 OK I issue another request of create/update next file.

Comment: I'm guessing you're hitting a corner case with the API due to these sequential writes that are happening one after another. Can you please try putting a sleep in your script so that you wait for a second or two between calls? That should resolve the issue. We're working on fixing this on our end, but I can't make any promises about when this will be resolved. Let me know if that doesn't help.

Comment: Thanks Ivan !! After your first comment I did same. I am making thread sleep for 500 ms and continue same. It worked fine. Thanks for hint !! I am just wondering on curiosity side, When I make http request with API, it is actually queuing up task on your end and later commit changes? It is my guess but you can confirm that.

Comment: I'm not sure, exactly -- there's a lot of things/layers involved and I'm not familiar with all the details (including caching, which always causes interesting problems). Glad to hear you managed to work around the problem! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Ivan suggested, if we try to create/update files using quick succession using API it causes mentioned behavior. Till issue is fixed we can workaround this by making thread sleep between two request. I hope it will help someone.