# Is it possible to attach a file to a GitHub Issue via the API?

Tags: jquery, git, post, github, github-api

I would like to create a GitHub issue with an attached excel spreadsheet via the GitHub API.
I can successfully create the issue, https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/
but can't find any info on how to upload a file with the API. I just need the file connected to the issue, I'm not picky if it's in the original issue post, or uploaded as a comment.

Is this possible? I figure not since I can't find docs, but wanted to check.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28703544/create-an-issue-with-image-via-github-api) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19576601/github-api-issue-with-file-upload) will answer your question

Comment: I saw both of those answers, the first is basically "no" but is a year old so I was hoping maybe things have changed. The second doesn't make a lot of sense, but the user seems to be uploading a file to a repo

Answer (score 2):

I came across this command line tool that uses the private API to do this: https://github.com/j178/github-s3

Answer (score 0):

At this time, there is no way to do that from the GitHub API.
Follow https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/1133

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30802297)